# Angular date filter with date-string

Tags: angularjs, date, angular-filters

I have a datestring in the following format: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS`

I want to use the Angular date filter in the binding to change it to a `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm` format.

I am trying `{{data.date | date : "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"}}`, but it doens't seem to work. Any ideas on what to change to get it to recognize my date format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

In Js file

```
angular.module('yourmodule').filter('datetime', function($filter)
{
 return function(input)
 {
  if(input == null){ return ""; } 

  var _date = $filter('date')(new Date(input),
                              'MMM dd yyyy - HH:mm:ss');

  return _date.toUpperCase();

 };
});
```

In HTML

```
<span>{{ d.time | datetime }}</span>
```

Comment: I'm trying to do the filtering in the HTML and not the javascript.