# Convert timestamp date into proper date format with month name

Tags: angular, typescript

Need to convert below timestamp date

```
var uploadDate = 2021-04-17T17:19:19.831Z
```

into proper date format with month name also like this - `04 Feb 2021`

in `.ts` file. I don't need that in html

How to get `this.uploadDate = 04 Feb 2021` like this.

Comment: Don't forget the quotes around string values!

Comment: Why not do this with [Angular's Date Pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) or [Angular JS Date Filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular date filter with date-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44743413/angular-date-filter-with-date-string)

Comment: i need month in string format like 'Feb' using new Date() is not doing that for me - @phuzi

Comment: For this format -> `04 Feb 2021` it will be better to use a library like moment, or date-fns. But you can use `new Date('2021-04-17T17:19:19.831Z').toLocaleDateString()` and the output will be "17/04/2021"  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: then use https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/ @Rose

Comment: No need to use `new Date()` just feed the filter the date string as you already have it. See my answer for more details. No need to use momentjs or custom date formatting code as it's already part of AngularJS

Comment: Why do you say "in .ts file. I don't need that in html"?

Comment: @CodingYoshi- since i need to send in that format to server.

Comment: @Rose, see my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Angular you can format a date like string using the [date filter](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) from [CommonModule](https://angular.io/api/common/CommonModule)

Inside your component:

```
this.myDate = "2021-04-17T17:19:19.831Z";
```

And in the view use the date filter to format the date however you like

```
{{ myDate | date: 'dd MMM yyyy'}}
```

This will give you:

```
17 Apr 2021
```

There's [a working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tbgyh2) over at Stackblitz

**Format date inside a Component**

You can also use the date pipe inside your component, inject it as you would any other dependency.

Include DatePipe in your module

```
import { DatePipe } from "@angular/common";

@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [DatePipe]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Add it to your component's dependencies:

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
```

Inside your component add the dependency to your class:

```
constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {}
```

And then you are free to format a date inside your component:

```
this.datePipe.transform(this.date, "dd MMM yyyy")
```

Comment: using your first answer DatePipe worked for me, after importing it from 'angular/common'..... Please edit your answer mentioning DatePipe, i will mark it as answer to my question :)

Comment: @Rose updated for Angular (instead of Angular JS)

Comment: marking it as answer, since exactly this is what worked for me

Answer (score 0):

```
var uploadDate = "2021-04-17T17:19:19.831Z";
var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
var d = new Date(uploadDate);
var month = monthNames[d.getMonth()];
var day = String(d.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
var year = d.getFullYear();
var formatedDate = day  + ' '+ month + ' ' + year;
console.log(formatedDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can:

```js
// first get Date from string
const getDateFromStr = (dateString) => new Date(Date.parse(dateString));
// setting options to format your Date
const dayFormatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', {
    day: 'numeric',
    month: 'short',
    year: 'numeric',
});
// format your Date
dayFormatter.format(getDateFromStr('2021-04-17T17:19:19.831Z'));
```

Here you can find more about Intl.DateTimeFormat:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat

And here about Date.parse

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Answer (score 0):

Using Vanilla Js we can use the toDateString() and tweak it's result a bit, to get the desired result, I am not aware about if this is the best way w.r.t angularjs

```
    let dateArr = new Date("2021-04-17T17:19:19.831Z").toDateString().split(" "); // the array would look like [ 'Sat', 'Apr', '17', '2021' ]
    dateArr.shift();  // removes the day(Sat) from the array
    console.log(dateArr.join(" ")); // Output: Apr 17 2021
```